# Formula to return left 6 chartacters if the first characters are numbers and show blank if first characters are text in cell

Tags: excel, string, if-statement, excel-formula, number-formatting

I am looking for a formula to return the first 6 numbers if the first characters in the cell are numbers and if the characters are text to show a blank cell.

Here is some of the data I am working with.

```
-DC DONE ON INV 10038 POSTED JULY

-399832 - Credit against CA00662835 

-Credit against CA00637779 - PO # 397811 L1 Q30 

-415862 - Credit against CA00662378 

-429002 L1 Q600
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Penny

Comment: It helps the community answer your question if you provide relevant code/screenshots/ and describe your problem in a bit more detail. Explain what you did, what is wrong, and what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in `A1`:

```
=IFERROR(--LEFT(A1,6),"")
```